# Randomly getting PGRES_FATAL_ERROR while writing into PostgreSQL DB

Tags: database, postgresql, fatal-error, postgresql-9.2

I have hit a dead end with this error `PGRES_FATAL_ERROR` while writing to my database(sequential writes). I see this error randomly during write operation and really hard to recreate and troubleshoot. I am using Postgres 9.2.9 on Windows Server 2003. I did increase the shared_memory to 128 MB on my VM as it has 1GB memory. However it did not make any difference. Below is how I am capturing the error message:

```
char* resStatus = PQresStatus(PQresultStatus(ires));
char* errMsg = PQerrorMessage(m_dbConn);
char* errorMsg = PQresultErrorMessage(ires);
```

When I try to log the error message, it is blank. What else I should do to prevent this error. Postgresql log posted below. My application log just shows the error "PGRES_FATAL_ERROR" (Issue time stamp from my app - 04/14 18:06:18.59)

```
2015-04-14 18:06:18.437 IST postgres    DataExpress 5112    127.0.0.1:2031  552d09c2.13f8   3   SELECT  2015-04-14 18:06:18 IST Apr-00  0   LOG 0   duration: 0.000 ms
2015-04-14 18:06:18.453 IST postgres    DataExpress 5112    127.0.0.1:2031  552d09c2.13f8   4   idle    2015-04-14 18:06:18 IST     0   LOG 0   disconnection: session time: 0:00:00.016 user=postgres database=DataExpress host=127.0.0.1 port=2031
2015-04-14 18:06:18.468 IST         2700        552d09c2.a8c    1       2015-04-14 18:06:18 IST     0   LOG 0   connection received: host=127.0.0.1 port=2032
2015-04-14 18:06:18.468 IST postgres    DataExpress 2700    127.0.0.1:2032  552d09c2.a8c    2   authentication  2015-04-14 18:06:18 IST Apr-30  0   LOG 0   connection authorized: user=postgres database=DataExpress
2015-04-14 18:06:18.484 IST postgres    DataExpress 2700    127.0.0.1:2032  552d09c2.a8c    3   SELECT  2015-04-14 18:06:18 IST Apr-00  0   LOG 0   duration: 0.000 ms
2015-04-14 18:06:18.484 IST postgres    DataExpress 2700    127.0.0.1:2032  552d09c2.a8c    4   idle    2015-04-14 18:06:18 IST     0   LOG 0   disconnection: session time: 0:00:00.016 user=postgres database=DataExpress host=127.0.0.1 port=2032
2015-04-14 18:06:18.578 IST postgres    DataExpress 3200    127.0.0.1:1955  552d09ae.c80    1160    INSERT  2015-04-14 18:05:58 IST Mar-00  0   LOG 0   duration: 141.000 ms
2015-04-14 18:06:18.593 IST postgres    DataExpress 3200    127.0.0.1:1955  552d09ae.c80    1161    INSERT  2015-04-14 18:05:58 IST Mar-00  0   LOG 0   duration: 15.000 ms
2015-04-14 18:06:18.718 IST         5188        552d09c2.1444   1       2015-04-14 18:06:18 IST     0   LOG 0   connection received: host=127.0.0.1 port=2033
2015-04-14 18:06:41.765 IST postgres    DataExpress 3200    127.0.0.1:1955  552d09ae.c80    1162    INSERT  2015-04-14 18:05:58 IST Mar-00  0   LOG 0   duration: 0.000 ms
2015-04-14 18:06:41.765 IST postgres    DataExpress 5188    127.0.0.1:2033  552d09c2.1444   2   authentication  2015-04-14 18:06:18 IST Apr-34  0   LOG 0   connection authorized: user=postgres database=DataExpress
2015-04-14 18:06:41.781 IST postgres    DataExpress 5188    127.0.0.1:2033  552d09c2.1444   3   SELECT  2015-04-14 18:06:18 IST Apr-00  0   LOG 0   duration: 0.000 ms
2015-04-14 18:06:41.781 IST postgres    DataExpress 5188    127.0.0.1:2033  552d09c2.1444   4   idle    2015-04-14 18:06:18 IST     0   LOG 0   disconnection: session time: 0:00:23.156 user=postgres database=DataExpress host=127.0.0.1 port=2033
```

Comment: Any more details in the postgres log file? Or the windows event log? Could be a hardware problem with the disk. Do you run a Virus scanner on that machine? If yes, turn it off - or at least exclude the Postgres data directory from scanning

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - No other useful information from event log or my logging. However, when i try to perform read operation (PqExec) after this failure, it reads successfully. Similarly next try for a write operation will be successful as well. It is kind of ON and OFF.I am not sure what is triggering this behavior.  Tried [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13473977/how-can-i-call-pl-pgsql-function-from-c-code)

Comment: That sounds very much like a problem with your virus scanner.

Comment: Checked the computer. No antivirus software installed and firewall is disabled

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name forgot to tag your name. There is no antivirus on this virtual machine.

Comment: Show the **full, exact error message* please. If your app doesn't display it, look in the PostgreSQL log files.

Comment: @CraigRinger I do have the postgresql log files. Is there a way to attach it here.

Comment: @Rag Edit the question and insert the relevant part of the log, the error you're getting. Then comment here when done.

Comment: So there's nothing in the PostgreSQL logs that looks relevant, and there's no message in the error you get. That sounds like it's a client-side issue where an error's generated by `libpq` rather than PostgreSQL its self.

Comment: @CraigRinger Yes. That is the mystery part. We are debugging on the application side now.